# What kind of inequality is this?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

What kind of inequality is this?

$|z^2 + 1|$ is greater than or equal to $|z|^2 - 1$

why $-1$? , and why not $-100\,000$?

does $z$ have to be a complex variable?

correction : sorry it was not $|z^2|$, it was $|z|^2$

Comment: Where is this inequality from?

Comment: Don't worry, $|z^2|=|z|^2$ !

Comment: It's the *triangle inequality*.

Answer (score 3):

If $z,w\in\Bbb C$, then $|z-w|\geqslant\bigl||z|-|w|\bigr|\geqslant|z|-|w|$. So, in particular,$$|z^2+1|=|z^2-(-1)|\geqslant|z^2|-1=|z|^2-1.$$

Comment: But is this tight ?

Comment: If by “tight” you mean that we sometimes have an equality, then, yes, it is tight: take $z=\pm i$, for instance.

Comment: Yep. In fact, that was the main question ("why $-1$ ?").

Answer (score 1):

In the reals,

$$z^2+1\ge z^2$$ holds (and the modulus is not even necessary).

But in the complex, a counter-example is

$$|i^2+1|=|i^2|-1=0.$$

---

Let $z^2=a+ib$ and let us look for the minimum of

$$\sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

We cancel the gradient,
$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{a+1}{\sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},
\\\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{(a+1)^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\end{cases}$$

and this implies $b=0$, and $z^2$ is real. The function reduces to

$$|a+1|-|a|$$ which has the minimum $-1$. Hence

$$|z^2+1|\ge|z^2|-1$$ is tight.